# Limited Precision calculation in Mathematica

Tags: numerics, precision-and-accuracy

I apologize upfront for the simple minded question, however i couldn't find an answer in either the Mathematica documentation or Stack exchange.

I am trying to explore the effect of finite precision in Mathematica, however i seem to miss how to limit calculation precision .
Here is a trivial example . Say i want to calculate the n'th power of x^n using various precessions. I tried something like this, however while the output becomes truncated the calculation is clearly not limited (see the result from two 2) ?

what am i missing, or better how would this be done correct ?

```
SetPrecision[Pi, 3]
SetPrecision[SetPrecision[Pi, 3]^8, 15]
SetAccuracy[Pi, 3]^8
Pi^8 // N
3.14^8
```

Comment: among other things note the precision of the literal `3.14` is not 3, but is `MachinePrecision`.   You should add `3.14\`3^8` to your test list

Answer (score 7):

Most *Mathematica* functions have no [side-effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29). This means that `SetPrecision` returns a version of its input in which all numbers have been set to a certain precision, but it does *not* influence the precision of the arguments themselves. In other words, it is the output of `SetPrecision` that has the requested precision; you will want to e.g. explicitly save the reduced-precision result in another variable in order to use it.

See the difference e.g. between the following expressions

```
pilow = SetPrecision[Pi, 3]
(* Out: 3.14 *)

N[Pi^8]
(* Out: 9488.53 *)

pilow^8
(* Out: 9.5*10^3 *)

3.14`3^8 (* this has the same precision as pilow *)
(* Out: 9.5*10^3 *)

3.14^8 (* this number actually has $MachinePrecision digits of precision *)
(* Out: 9450.12 *)
```

---

The precision of these results can be  probed explicitly:

```
Precision[Pi^8]      (* Infinity         *)
Precision[N[Pi^8]]   (* MachinePrecision *)
Precision[pilow^8]   (* 2.09691          *)
Precision[3.14^8]    (* MachinePrecision *)
Precision[3.14`3^8]  (* 2.09691          *)
```

Alternatively, one can read the precision off e.g. the `FullForm` of any numerical result:

```
FullForm[pilow]      (* 9488.5310160705740071286`2.0969100130080567 *)
```

Comment: Thx a lot Marco, however to be honest your answer sounds puzzling to me. For one would you also say the instead of Sort[2.0]^8 i should use a= Sort[2.0]; a^2 ? I think the whole notion of Functional programming is to daisy chain functions ?  Beside that your suggestion still gives the unexpected value that the limited precision calculation yields the full precision result ?

Comment: **1)** I am not sure what `Sort[2.0]` would achieve, but e.g. `f[x]^2` is in fact daisy-chaining functions, i.e. you obtain `Power[f[x], 2]`, which you could equivalently write as `Power[#, 2]& @f[x]` to highlight the daisy-chain: this calculates the return value of f when applied to x, then feeds the return value to `Power`. Am I missing your point? **2)** The limited precision calculation does *not* yield a full precision result. You can convince yourself of that by noting the precision digits associated with the result in `FullForm[pilow^8]`, or explicitly by running `Precision[pilow^8]`.

Comment: @bernddude Please see my comment above, and the edit to my answer.

Comment: Marco, thx a lot once again. Sorry for the typo, spellchecker feature Sqrt-> Sort nice :). I do under stand your point, I feel its more that SetPrecision does behave different then i would expect . Below is one more example N[Pi, 20]
SetPrecision[Pi, 3]
pillow = SetPrecision[Pi, 3]
FullForm[N[Pi^8]]
pillow^8
FullForm[pillow^8]
FullForm[3.14^8]
pillow^8 - 3.14^8   the last line gives the result 38.414

Comment: Marco here might be a better example of what i am trying to say .   p = 200
e = .996
ep = SetPrecision[e, 2]
SetPrecision[e^p, 3]
e^p
ep^p
SetPrecision[ep, 20]^p       i would expect for ep^100 to get 1 after the assignment is done. Obviously this isn't wrong however in order to "simulate" the behavior of a finite precision embedded system, its not that useful .